# Is induction needed for this argument?

Tags: induction, solution-verification

This question is about Exercise 13 in Section 1-1 of *Number Theory* by George E. Andrews. The book says:

> The Lucas numbers $L_n$ are defined by the equations $L_1 = 1$, and $L_n = F_{n + 1} + F_{n - 1}$ for each $n \geq 2$. We also have that

> $\textbf{Claim: }\ L_n = L_{n - 1} + L_{n - 2}\ \text{ for }\ n \geq 3$.

$\textit{My attempt at a proof: }$
We approach by mathematical induction. For the base case, consider when $n = 3$. We have that $L_3 = F_4 + F_2 = 3 + 1 = (2 + 1) + 1 = (F_3 + F_1) + 1 = L_2 + L_1$ so, the claim holds when $n = 1$. Now suppose the claim holds for an integer $k > 1$. Then,
\begin{align*}
    L_{k + 1} &= F_{k + 2} + F_k && \text{definition of Lucas number}\\
    &= (\underline{F_k} + \underline{\underline{F_{k + 1}}}) + (\underline{F_{k - 2}} + \underline{\underline{F_{k - 1}}}) && \text{Fibonacci recurrence}\\
    &= L_{k - 1} + L_k && \text{definition of Lucas number}.
\end{align*}
Hence, the claim also holds for the integer $k + 1$. By the principle of mathematical induction, the claim holds for all $n \geq 3$.

The problem I'm having is that I haven't used the inductive hypothesis. So, I am confused whether my proof is wrong or if the argument doesn't require induction, etc.

I have done a quick search and it seems that the Lucas numbers are usually defined by $L_0 = 2$, $L_1 = 1$, and $L_n = L_{n - 1} + L_{n - 2}$ for  $n \geq 3$. And the problem is usually to show $L_n = F_{n + 1} + F_{n - 1}$ for each $n \geq 2$. Would this be a typo in the book or a misunderstanding on my end?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct when you say that your proof does not use induction. It's a straightforward argument using the definition given for the Lucas numbers and the property of the Fibonacci numbers.

The conclusion is that the Lucas and Fibonacci numbers satisfy the same recursive condition.

Then to recover the definition you found for the Lucas numbers you need just check the original conditions.

Since the definitions are in fact equivalent, there's no reason to assume that there's a typo in the book.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I will try to prove that the definitions are equivalent for more practice.